# Regular Expression Validation behaves different in ASP.NET MVC Validation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have the following regex data validation to restrict the user input to two places after decimal if it even exists.

```
-1 is acceptable
1 is acceptable
12 is acceptable
12.25 is acceptable
12.275 is NOT ACCEPTABLE
12. is NOT ACCEPTABLE
```

I also want to restrict and not allow 12. so I added this regex pattern

```
"^(-?\d*\.?\d{1,2})$"
```

Online Regex tools say 12. is not acceptable, however when I added it in ASP.NET MVC validation, it seems to be ok with 12. and doesn't display validation error.

Comment: You could try it like this `^-?\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$`

Comment: The possible number of decimal digits should be restricted
^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$